# Files returned by NSFileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL do not exist according to NSFileManager.fileExistsAtPath?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, file-io, nsfilemanager

### New version

In iOS app I need to read several text files that are placed in resource bundle. I created following test code in class `MyClass`:

```
private let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: MyClass.self)

private func testLoadResource() {
    var error: NSError? = NSError()
    for fileUrl in NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(bundle.resourceURL!,
        includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.allZeros, error: &error)! {
        print("\(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath((fileUrl as! NSURL).absoluteString!)), ")
    }
}
```

The console output of this code is:

```
false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false
```

So the files found by `NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL` do not exist according to `NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath`?! How is that possible?

Apparently, resource files that I put in resource bundle can by found by `contentsOfDirectoryAtURL` but not by `fileExistsAtPath` function of `NSFileManager`. And I also cannot find the way how to read them. Please help.

Also note, that both the class `MyClass` (with testing code above) and the resource text files I need to read are located in iOS framework.

### Original question

In my iOS app need to read several text files that I put in resource bundle. However, I have great trouble with reading those files from code. I created following test code:

```
private let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: MyClass.self)

private func testLoadResource() {
    var error: NSError? = NSError()
    if let k = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(bundle.resourceURL!, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.allZeros, error: &error) {
        for i in k {
            println(String(contentsOfFile: (i as! NSURL).absoluteString!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error))
            println(error)
        }
    }
}
```

For all the text files I put in the bundle the above code produces following error output:

```
Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)" 
UserInfo=0x17407aa40 {NSFilePath=file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/73BEA20A-FC36-46EB-B27B-2124FF24BAFD/EasyType.app/Frameworks/EasyTypeShared.framework/blurredTest.text, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x17404e5b0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"})
```

`blurredTest.text` is name of the file I placed in the bundle. The file apparently exists because its URL is returned by `contentsOfDirectoryAtURL` for folder `bundle.resourceURL!` but it the error says it does not exist! Also testing for existence with `NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(i)` returns `false`.

Please not that the text file `blurredTest.text` is located in iOS framework as well as reading code in class `MyClass` (above).

So how do I read that file?

Comment: @RizwanShaikh That answer talks gives solution to entirely different problem - my files are really just a files, not directories.

Answer (score -1):

The array you get back from `NSFileManager`'s `contentsOfDirectoryAtURL` are strings that contain the name of each file in the directory of the passed in path. If for example your bundle path was `/MyGreatApp/Resources/` and you had a file named `SomeText.txt` in it the array that came back from `contentsOfDirectoryAtURL` would be `SomeText.txt`, not `/MyGreatApp/Resources/SomeText.txt`. As a result when you grab an item from the array and ask the file manager if it exists it looks at `/SomeText.txt` instead of `/MyGreatApp/Resources/SomeText.txt` where the file actually is.

If you take each result in the array you get from `contentsOfDirectoryAtURL` and append it to the end of the bundle url you should see much better results.

Comment: I think this is not correct solution. Before checking whether the file exists I am calling `absoluteString` on each `NSURL` returned by `contentsOfDirectoryAtURL`. That efectively expands path relative to bundle's resource directory to absolute path but `fileExistsAtPath ` check still returns `false`. However I might just misuderstood your answer. Could you provide code sample?

Comment: Add this right before your existing print line, it should clear things up for you: `print("\((fileUrl as! NSURL).absoluteString!)")`. If you have a complete path then something else is wrong, if not you need to try something more like: `var url = bundle.resourceURL!; url = url.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileURL!); print("\(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(url.path)")`

Comment: I already did that - I have complete path. Thank you for ideas anyway.